# Adding a primary key to a large table on a shared database server

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a large database of zip / postal codes used in proximity searches. There are about 1 million records. Somehow I didn't add the primary key to the table, and now I have to add it because searches take about 3 seconds because of the full table scan. When I go to generate a script to add it in SSMS, the operation times out because it is creating a new table and important the data. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the execution timeout in your SSMS Options/Query Execution is set to 0 (no timeout).  Then use a query similar to the following with table/column/key names replaced with yours.  Adjust the parameters as desired.

```
ALTER TABLE tableName WITH NOCHECK 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_tableName PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (columnName)
WITH (FILLFACTOR = 75, ONLINE = ON, PAD_INDEX = ON)
```

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Generate the script and paste it into a query and run it there.  Make sure your SSMS is not set to have an execution time-out in the options.

Answer (score 0):

why not just create a unique index?

Answer (score -2):

ALTER TABLE  ADD PRIMARY KEY (,etc...)

Should work in MySQL.